# Mouseover on all elements in frame only responds to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to apply a handler to all the elements inside an iframe (that is on the same domain) and I can't figure out why it the function only fires on click. I fear it may have to do with the fact that the iframe is only active when I'm clicking into it. I have seen applications of this in a jsfiddle such as this http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/pMBw2/

This is basically my code (I tried mimicking the jsfiddle using the delegate function and got the same results):

```
            $('iframe').contents().on("mouseover", "*", function() {
                 $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
```

**EDIT**
working with that jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/pMBw2/) I found that if you switch it to the newest version of jquery 2.1.0, then the code no longer works, it seems 1.8.3 is the newest one that works with that code.

Comment: Any reason you are using jQuery 1.4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me -

```
var $c = $('iframe').contents();
$c.delegate('div', 'hover', function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Comment: Why did this get down voted? Is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mimicing the jsfiddle you mentioned should work just fine, you have to use the `delegate()` function:

[Working js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/pMBw2/161/)

```
<iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net"></iframe>

var $c = $('iframe').contents();

$c.delegate('div', "hover", function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Comment: hmm, you're right this does work on the jsfiddle. there must be something weird with my code.

Comment: @TareqPerez is your test page viewable online?

Comment: I think the fact that there were so many elements on the page it was causing the iframe to become unresponsive and crash in chrome. Thanks for confirming I had it right though!

Comment: @TareqPerez, just curious, why would you change the selected answer to  another answer exactly the same as this one but posted later?